# How to hide the cursor in hololens2?

Tags: hololens, mrtk

How to hide the cursor in hololens2?

I need to use handray, and get the hit point coordinate to set my gameobject position like

```
GameObject manipulatePoint

foreach (var source in CoreServices.InputSystem.DetectedInputSources)
            {
                if (source.SourceType is InputSourceType.Hand)
                {
                    foreach (var p in source.Pointers)
                    {

                        if (p is ShellHandRayPointer && p.Result != null)
                        {
                            if (p.PointerName == "Right_ShellHandRayPointer(Clone)")
                            {
                                var endPoint = p.Result.Details.Point;
                                var hitObject = p.Result.Details.Object;
                                if (hitObject != null)
                                {
                                    var rayPosition = p.Result.Details.Point;
                                    var rayNormal = p.Result.Details.Normal;
                                    manipulatePoint.transform.position = rayPosition;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

But there is a default cursor show on the intersection of ray and object. Is there any method to hide the cursor (hide by script, or edit the default cursor). Thanks.

I tried to make my hand ray, but result is not as expected. I don't know how to make vector forward like MRTK handray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customize the hand ray prefab in **MRTK Profile/Input/Pointers**. **DefaultHoloLens2ConfigurationProfile** uses **ShellHandRayPointer** as the hand ray prefab by default, and **DefaultGazeCursor** is used as the cursor prefab by default. Feel free to delete or replace it. Please refer to [Pointers - MRTK 2 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/features/input/pointers?view=mrtkunity-2022-05) for more information.

Regarding making hand rays, have you tried Raycast - [Unity - Scripting API: Physics.Raycast (unity3d.com)](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)?

Comment: Oh, it just copy ShellHandRayPointer prefab and edit XD. Thanks a lot.